# Removing the last part of the site URLs from autocomplete

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-tools, moderators

In the close-as-off-topic list, the migration autocomplete catches the URLs of the sites. This limits its usefulness for strings like "com" since almost all sites end in "stackexchange.com".

I think it would better if the autocomplete only catches the first part of the URLs (till the first dot), that would increase its usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

Since the following "p" reduces the set of all sites down to the 3 that would matter...is this really an issue?

Let's see the list "co" would still match if we *didn't* match the full URLs:

- Cooking
- Theoretical Computer Science
- Code Review
- Code Golf
- Bitcoin
- Economics
- Computational Science
- Cognitive Sciences
- Computer Science

...not a very specific list.  If we check "com":

- Theoretical Computer Science
- Computational Science
- Computer Science

The difference in the same, "comp" or stripping out ".com" - it's literally 1 character here by the numbers. I'd rather leave it working in a consistent way...vs. possibly breaking non-.com domains later.

Comment: Well we could drop the .com for all compares, pretend the thing being matched is just physics.stackexchange .. Course you could make the same argument for .stackexchange really

Comment: I think part of the problem is it doesn't start autocompleting at the start of words...the first result for U is Android Enthusiasts, not User Experience...

Comment: even one letter is one letter if you are doing it repeatedly. I think Ben has a good point also, matching initial parts seems more reasonable, I don't have statistics but my guess is that matching initial parts can be more helpful.

Comment: If we get to a point where we *need* to search in *that* dialog on the *full* DNS name (because we have non-.com DNS names in there), then we're using the wrong UX at that point.

Comment: I'm going to hold off on changing this, as there may be other area51-related migration changes in the future that'll likely change the behavior *again* here.